# Exception while connecting when i am in 2 different networks, (gmail-imap-java)

Tags: java

I am trying to use JavaMail talk to gmail/imap, but could not make it work. I am behind firewall and have the right setting for proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaMail does not currently support accessing mail servers through a web proxy server.